# 'FuseIT SFDC Explorer' tool for importing WSDL(with multiple import, include tag and XSD files)

Tags: wsdl2apex, fuseit

I am trying to import a WSDL in FuseIT tool which has multiple nesting of XSD and other WSDLs in it. I have a folder with all XSD and WSDL files. Now I want to remove nesting from WSDL and combine all data in one file in order to use it in Salesforce. I want to remove import, include and binding tags from WSDL. Can anybody suggest me how to do it?

Comment: You can use the offline [wsdl2apex](https://github.com/forcedotcom/WSDL2Apex) code, as far as I understand it, but there may be additional complications, as Apex web services do not support all the various types of wsdl modes out there. I don't have the experience to write an authoritative answer though, but if you're so inclined, you can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

One of the primary reasons I created the FuseIT version of WSDL2Apex was to avoid the need to flatten the imported XSDs into the parent WSDL. The process is prone to failure and will often cause more issues. Also, it becomes a significant burden if you have to frequently deal with WSDL changes.

The FuseIT WSDL2Apex should automatically bring in the imported schema and still produce the required Apex classes. The only requirement here is that it can successfully resolve the paths of the imported XSDs.

If the XSD files are in the same directory as the parent WSDL then the `xs:import` statements would look something like:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema>
        <xs:import namespace="http://child.schema.com/elements/global" schemaLocation="child.xsd" />
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

With that input the related schema will be automatically imported and the required Apex classes generated.